# Some properties of the content of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> 1. Let $F \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, with
>    $gcd(a,b)=1$, and a primitive polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ that $F
>    = \dfrac{a}{b}f$,
> 2. Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Show using Gauss's lemma that:
>    $$cont(fg)=cont(f)cont(g)$$

My idea for 1 was took $a=gcd(a_0,...a_n)$ and $b=lcm(b_0,...,b_n)$, then picking $f = \dfrac{b}{a}F$, but I'm not sure of it.

For 2, I though doing $f = cont(f).f^*$ and $g=cont(g).g^*$, with $f^*$ and $g^*$ being primitive polynomials. Then we would have $f^*g^*$ primitive by Gauss's lemma, and then:
$$cont(fg) = cont(cont(f)cont(g)f^*g^*) = cont(f)cont(g)cont(f^*g^*) = cont(f)cont(g).$$
because by definition $cont(f^*g^*)=1$.

**OBS:** $cont(f)$ is the content of the polynomial $f$.

Comment: For (1), you can clear denominators first and then take the gcd of the resulting (integer) coefficients.

Comment: But how can I guarantee that the $gcd(a,b)=1?$

Comment: You then simplify the fraction. Any fraction $\frac{r}{s}$ with $r$ and $s$ integers can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.